# Magento - API Stock Qty Update (SLOW AS HELL)

Tags: api, magento, csv, product

right i'm using the Magento API to update stock, however i'm using a CSV export of products that contains product skus that do exist in magento and ones that don't

so when the sku list is 3 long it works fine.

when it's 8k+ long it breaks. e.g. it chuggs and wurrs and then 'php white screens of death'

my code also stops special skus from not being inputted(don't ask) they're all the pre_match stuff.

so my code looks like this:

```
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.magentosite/index.php/api/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('user', 'apikey');


if (($handle = fopen("../stock.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {


            if(count($proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_stock.list', $data[1])) > 0 && (preg_match('/specialcode1/', $data[1]) || preg_match('/^specialcode2/i', $data[1]) || preg_match('/specialcode3/', $data[1]))){

                        $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_stock.update', array($data[1], array('qty'=>$data[2])));

            }

}
}
fclose($handle);





echo 'complete';
```

so i understand the API can be quite slow, it does *touch wood* seem to complete down to the last sku but still fires a white php error.

any ideas on if it's my code being crap or if its just the nature of the API?

regards
Andy.

Answer (score 7):

Each API call has a big overhead, namely Magento's extensive OOP system. With a bit of thought the number of calls can be reduced.

```
if (($handle = fopen("../stock.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $qtyBySku = array();
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        // first column ($data[0]) is ignored.
        list(, $sku, $qty) = $data;
        $qtyBySku[$sku] = (float) $qty;
    }
    fclose($handle);

    $skus = preg_grep('/specialcode1|^specialcode2|specialcode3/',
                array_keys($qtyBySku));
    if ($skus) try {
        $proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.magentosite/index.php/api/?wsdl');
        $sessionId = $proxy->login('user', 'apikey');

        // Break into blocks of 100 because it's TOO efficient
        foreach (array_chunk($skus, 100) as $skuChunk) {
            $stock = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_stock.list',
                         array($skuChunk));
            if ($stock) {
                $calls = array();
                foreach ($stock as $product) {
                    $sku = $product['sku'];
                    $qty = $qtyBySku[$sku];
                    $calls[] = array(
                        'product_stock.update', array($sku, array(
                            'qty' => $qty,
                            // only in stock if qty is high enough
                            'is_in_stock' => $qty > 0
                        ))
                    );
                }
                $proxy->multiCall($sessionId, $calls);
            }
        }
        $proxy->endSession($sessionId);

        echo 'complete';
    }
    catch (SoapFault $err) {
        echo $err;
        // or do something more interesting here
    }
    // else nothing to update
}
```

Notice a few common sense changes:

- File is opened and closed before logging into API, it's quick to check for a file and slow to make a network connection.
- SKU is checked for special code before `product_stock.list`, there is only a logon if any SKUs match. Again it is quicker to do the local work than the remote.
- A single regex is used instead of multiple, and `preg_grep` only parses the expression once, instead of once per record.
- [`product_stock.list`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/cataloginventory_stock_item#cataloginventory_stock_item.list) takes an array of IDs or SKUs, meaning you can lookup all records in one go.
- You don't need to wait for [`product_stock.update`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/cataloginventory_stock_item#cataloginventory_stock_item.update) to return a value (although it has one) which means you can do many at once in `multiCall`.

Comment: Hi Clockwork, thanks for the detailed write up. I'm especially loving the 'common sense changes' - Being Front end means when it comes to major-ish code common sense goes out the window, i usually opt for a 'less is more approach' - and clearly that doesn't work for coding time to tell this company to employ a proper developer for the 100th time :) thanks again ill look through the code closer at some point today.

Comment: Hi again clockwork ok i found that with your code, $stock was empty. so i changed this line to: $stock = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_stock.list', array($skus)); However i get a soap error now of: SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs/stock/index.php:69 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__call('multiCall', Array) #2 /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs/stock/index.php(69): SoapClient->multiCall('af4e9f3e4bf5fc3...', Array) #3 {main} - any ideas?

Comment: Is `$skus` also empty when the call is made?

Comment: if i do print_r($skus) that has values, but until i added $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_stock.list', array($skus)); did it produce an non empty output.

Comment: I tested on one of my own stores and you're right, the SKUs do need to be nested in another array, thank you for the correction. For your error perhaps try passing in fewer SKUs, we may find the server is crashing and needs to be fed batches of 1000 or less at a time. Also you can add `array('trace'=>true)` when constructing the `SoapClient` and then `echo $proxy->__getLastRequest()` when there is an error, that is useful for debugging.

Comment: Hi Clockwork, yeah i did try it with a test CSV that only had about 10 SKu's and there was no errors with that so your assumption of it timingout/crashing is probably quite likely. Hmm ok i'll have to give this more thought, thanks for your help thus far :)

Comment: hmm also to add to this, i added an echo foreach and it does seem like it's getting to the end of the array fine. but it is just outputing this error at the end. hmm i dont even understand what it means.

Comment: hmm ok that error after getting it eventually kills our Magento database, have to force restarts of mysql and delete cache and lock tables. the error i get                                                a:4:{i:0;s:115:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111";i:1;s:3010:"#0 /var/www/mysite.co.uk/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()

Comment: I've modified the code to split up requests in a simple manner, look for `array_chunk($skus, 100)`. This is still 100 times fewer API calls so should be a significant speed boost. Increase that number to increase batch size, decrease to avoid these awkward crashes.

Comment: Hi Clockworkgeek, so would this mean the script would have to run X number of times for the magento to have all it's qty's updated? or does it just throttle itself?

Comment: Hi Clockwork, alas this still fires this error: SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs/stock/index.php:72 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__call('multiCall', Array) #2 /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs/stock/index.php(72): SoapClient->multiCall('2bdf48a49561965...', Array) #3 {main}

Comment: @clockworkgeek Could you pin a sample of your stock.csv up so we can see what you're working with? Thanks greatly.

Comment: @ehime 3 columns - ID | SKU | QTY       - and there is about 9000 skus

Comment: Cool, I got it working via example, it turned out to be very slow so wrote this one instead which directly modifies the database. we did 12k sku's in about 45 seconds. I took your queue of ingesting a CSV file though, it seemed like a brilliant idea. Here's a stamp of mine. http://pastebin.com/616JSzks

Comment: I liked the `// Break into blocks of 100 because it's TOO efficient` part.